# Query plan ignores index on large join

Tags: sql-server

I have the following fairly simple query that returns about 1 million rows (I've left out columns as they are just for output), but the query plan doesn't seem to want to use the index and wants me to create one:

```
SELECT [SAU]
      ,nr.[Headend]
      ,[Source]
      ,[Destination]
      ,[FibreHop]
      ,[CableRef]
      ,[CableSectionRef]
      ,[nNGAFibres]
      ,[nEthFibres]
      ,[FromID]
      ,[ToID]
      ,[FromIDTerm]
      ,[ToIDTerm],Reversed
      ,@Now
  FROM [NodeRouting] nr 
  join [TargetHeadends] tex ON nr.Headend=tex.Headend
```

The index is:

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NodeRouting_Headend] ON [NodeRouting]
 (
     [Headend] ASC
 )
```

the other table Headend is the PK

The query plan is this:
[image]

[image]

If I give it a hint to use the index already created (non-unique, non-clustered) on the id field:

```
  join [TargetHeadends] tex ON nr.id=tex.id (index=NodeRouting_Headend)
```

It changes to this:
[image]
[image]

The estimated number of rows, btw, in reality is the first 966,000. The RID 761,000 is a few hundred thousand short and the operator cost seems a lot higher

One thing that is striking me as a little odd, is in the first example where it chose to not use the index it says this:

```
Missing Index (impact 99): CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX <NAME> ON NodeRouting(id) include (....)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name>]
ON [NodeRouting] ([Headend])
INCLUDE ([SAU],[Source],[Destination],[FibreHop],[CableRef],[CableSectionRef],[nNGAFibres],[nEthFibres],[FromID],[ToID],[FromIDTerm],[ToIDTerm],[Reversed])
```

I appreciate i'm returning more columns than in the index but would have thought the index would have still been used without the INCLUDE?

Comment: You'd be better off asking at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It will help a lot if you  share the original query.

Comment: "I've left out columns as they are just for output": What you select is also important for index choice and performance. That RID lookup is because of a selected column (probably what sql server wants in the `INCLUDE`). What's the code for the existing index?

Comment: I've updated as per requested, thanks.

Comment: As @HoneyBadger said, columns returned are important for plan selection. If you are returning non indexed columns and do not filter results (i.e.no `WHERE` clause) then optimiser thinks that it is more efficient to use a table scan.

Comment: The existing index can only be used to get the `headend`. For all the other columns the table still has to be scanned. Since most or all rows of the table are required, sql server thinks the index is of no use and a table scan is quicker (as it has to do that anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Indexes don't always help and they should not need to be forced into use.  For example, for small tables a scan will be used because it's less work because of index overhead. Don't force the use of the index.

For a large table, an index helps when it is "selective" and the query is selective. It will get a few records quickly. It does not get a lot of records quickly. If the index is more than about 5% selective, then it might be used. If not, a scan might be faster than using the non-selective index.

If you are returning all the records, then there is no selectivity. A scan is going to be more efficient. For the join, other methods are more efficient than the lookup for a lot of records.

Using a phonebook analogy, just start at the front of the phone book and read it to the end. Don't start at the start of the index and lookup each name one at a time until you get to the end of the index.

A covered index can help because it can be scanned in place of scanning the original table (clustered index). For example, if you have a two phone books where one has address information and the other does not, then reading the one without address information will be faster if you are not interested in addresses.

FWI: Don't trust the order of the columns for the index suggestions. Also, the index suggested in this case might be a covering index to avoid reading unneeded columns - not for selectivity.